# Cannot retrieve object information passed from php to twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a course description web page as a university project, where I'm currently working on the page where I'm displaying information regarding the approval status of all the courses. I'm retrieving all the courses stored in a database to an array in php, and then passing this array to the twig-file where I want to iterate through the course-array.

However twig doesn't seem to recognize what the 'course' variable in 'courseList' is, as no information is displayed.

**Twig**

```
<tbody>
        {% for course in courseList %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ loop.index }}</th>
            <td>{{ course.getCourseCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ course.getCourseName(0, course.getCourseId) }}</td>
            <td class="font-weight-bold">{{ course.getCourseApprovalDue }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar {% if course.getStatus == 0 %} bg-warning
                    {% elseif coruse.getStatus == 1 %} bg-danger {% else %} bg-success {% endif %}" role="progressbar"
                         style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10">{{ course.getStatus }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

**PHP**

```
if ($session->has('loggedin')) {

    $courseList = $database->getAllCourses();

    echo $twig->render('courseStatus.twig', array('user' => $session->get('user'), 'loggedIn' => true, 'courseList' => $courseList));
} else {
    echo $twig->render('login.twig');
}
```

The database queries and the php functions are working properly. I can verify this by passing a hardcoded course object to the twig file. The coruseList array isn't empty either, as the twig file displays 5 rows when rendering it, which is the same amount as the courses stored in the database.

Comment: Problem must be in `getAllCourses()` it's not returning data in the format you think it's returning in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array returned from getAllCourses() does not create a new instance of Course, it's just an array containing arrays with Course-data. The solution is to get the arrays, and create a new array with Course-objects with the information returned, and pass this array to the php-file.